# ssh asking for password for private key

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

so I want to connect windows server remotely on linux server using ssh on remmina and I have copied the public key to the windows server in the correct path but whenever I try to connect it prompts for password for private key with I did not set.

Comment: Try entering a blank password. If that does not work, try creating a new private-public keypair and setting the password to one that you can easily remember

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You have this tagged [windows-subsystem-for-linux] which is a feature in Windows that allows you to run Ubuntu. Is that really what you are using?  Your question doesn't seem to indicate that.  If not, when you get a chance, edit this to remove that tag (and probably add something ssh related).  Also, `ssh -vvvvv` can provide some more information.